# set the enum value in the string parameter

Tags: java, enums

The problem that all enum values must be set in the parameter, but only restitusice null, how come? This is the code

```
public class StatusKeys {
    public Priority keys = null;

    public enum Priority {
        OGG, SAC, PPP;
    }

    public Priority getKeys() {
        return keys;
    }

    public void setKeys(Priority keys) {
        this.keys = keys;
    }


public EnhancedStatusInfoRp xxx (String keys) {     
        StatusKeys keysConst = null;
        EnhancedStatusInfoSCT01UpdateSPRequest.Keys chiave = new EnhancedStatusInfoSCT01UpdateSPRequest.Keys();
        String myKey = keysConst.getKeys().valueOf(keys).toString(); ---> return null??????
        chiave.setValore(myKey);
        request.getKeys().add(chiave);
    }
```

Comment: Because keyConst is null. It should throw a null pointer exception.

Comment: Put a complete example. In the actual code, `keyConst`is `null`. This will throw a NullPointerException. Plus `keys`is `null` in `StatusKeys,` why would it return a different value?

Comment: What does *"all enum values must be set in the parameter"* mean? How can ***all*** of them be set in a single parameter, unless that parameter is an array or some kind of `Collection`?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
String myKey = Priority.valueOf(keys).toString();
```

Comment: This works, but enum I want to pass all the keys in myKey, how do I do it? I want to pass multiple keys together

Comment: @javabeginner Pass to where? --- Pass ***all*** in what format? Array? `List`? Comma-separated `String`? Something else?

Comment: always in my parameter --> keys, I want to pass all my keys to it